# Update object property in child process when property is changed in parent process

Tags: python, multithreading, events, multiprocessing

I would like to get object property updated in child process after I change it in the parent process. If I understand this correctly, at the moment of creating child process object will be replicated and changing properties in main process will not affect properties in child process. Here's an example of what I have so far:

```
class Sample(object):

    __init__(self, var_name):
        self.var_name = var_name
        # And many more, like IP, port etc, client_buffers.

    def run(self):

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))  
        self.socket.listen(5)  

        self.listener = threading.Thread(target=self.acceptor)
        self.listener.start()

     def acceptor(self):

        while True:

              conn, address = self.socket.accept()
              buffer = multiprocessing.Queue()
              self.client_buffers.append(buffer)

              process = multiprocessing.Process(
                    target=self.hanlder, args=(conn, address, buffer))

              process.start()
              conn.close  

    def handler(self, conn, address, buffer):

        while True: 
            print("Child var: %d", var_name)
            conn.sendall(buffer.get())
```

I would like to when I change `var_name` in the main process to change it also in the child process. Is it possible to do it with declaring object as global, without `Event`, `ConditionVariable` or `Variable`? Example:

```
s = Sample(5)
s.run()
sleep(2)
s.var_name = 10
sleep(2)
print("Parent var: %d, s.var_name")
s.join()
```

And output will look like:

```
Child var: 5
Child var: 5
Child var: 5
Parent var: 10
Child var: 5
Child var: 5
...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Once the child process begins it can't read updated data from the parent memory.

You will have to use some other mechanism to share the data around

Comment: @user3599280 Google "python interprocess communication"

Answer (score 1):

Using a Pipe is an effective method of inter process communication.